# How to make a batch file that knows if a txt file has been changed

Tags: batch-file, chat

i made a chat program and it records all the data on a txt file. I want it to be so nobody can change it. Is there a way to make it so my program knows if that file has been changed?

Comment: what if they change the batch file

Comment: @Sneftel I can convert it to exe so it is uneditable.

Comment: @hunterguimont - there's no such thing as "uneditable." Also, batch-to-exe converters _never_ work, and only cause more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: @SomethingDark he one i use works perfectly fine never causes any problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to settle for minimal certainty that the file has been unmodified, you could simply calculate the length of the data and append it to the end of the text file before saving. Then, upon reload, compare the length of the file with that calculated length. Not a perfect solution by any means, but it might be enough, depending on your needs.

Comment: @hunterguimont - StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Try it yourself and then post your code here and we'll tell you what you did wrong.